# ExtJs:How to set title of fieldset center?

Tags: extjs

Use html can easily accomplish this:

title

How to do it with Ext.form.FieldSet?
Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the CSS classes such as x-fieldset-header, it's probably left padded or somesuch and you should be able to override this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you can easily center the text since you don't have access to add an attribute to the tag.  Adding `text-align:center;` to the CSS does not seem to work.  You can approximate centering it if your fieldset is fixed-width by giving the legend a left margin:

```
.x-fieldset legend {
    margin-left: 80px;
}
```